# The correctness of creating a thread inside a loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I am not sure whether such code is safe or not. I need to read a name from the DB, and I need to use, say 10 threads, each one take a name, then inside the `run` it calls a function that needs this name as an argument.

Is 10 threads a suitable number for pc running Intel core i7 with 8GB RAM ?? How can I know the acceptable number of threads I can create? Is this code correct and safe?

I find in Dietel book that they create new thread before the Executor. They add line like: `PrintTask task1 = new PrintTask( "thread1" );`

check: http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20051126/JavaMultithreading_Tutorial_Part4.html) , but find the below method (without the new statement) in: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

In other word, should I create them before the loop? Two references use different methods and I'm confused. Which code is correct, this:

```
        ExecutorService Executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        while(resultSet.next()) 
           {
              name=resultSet.getString("hname");
              MyRunnable worker = new  MyRunnable(name);

               Executor.execute( worker );
               Counter++;
        }


     Executor.shutdown();
     System.out.println("thread shutdown");

// Wait until all threads are finish
while (! Executor.isTerminated()) {

}
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

OR

```
MyRunnable task1 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task2 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task3 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task4 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task5 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task6 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task7 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task8 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task9 = new MyRunnable(name );
MyRunnable task10 = new MyRunnable(name );


        ExecutorService Executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        while(resultSet.next()) 
           {
              name=resultSet.getString("hname");
              MyRunnable worker = new  MyRunnable(name);

               Executor.execute( worker );
               Counter++;
        }


     Executor.shutdown();
     System.out.println("thread shutdown");

// Wait until all threads are finish
while (! Executor.isTerminated()) {

}
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

Also, in the constructor of MyRunnable class that implements run, do i have to start the thread explicitly or does the `Executor.execute( worker )` enough in this case.

Comment: The runnables are *not* threads. They just have a run method that tells the thread that will eventually execute it what to do. And yes, Executor takes care of starting and stopping threads.

Comment: What does `MyRunnable.shutdown()` do? Did you mean `Executor.shutdown()`?

Comment: @Thilo: yes, it should be `Executor.shutdown`. Corrected now.

Comment: @Thilo: So, your comment means that there is no need to explicitly create new thread, or start it in the constructor ? i.e, the first code is correct ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have rewritten it like that:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

while(resultSet.next())
{
    name=resultSet.getString("hname");
    MyRunnable worker = new  MyRunnable(name);
    executor.submit(worker);
    counter++;
}


executor.shutdown();
System.out.println("thread shutdown");

executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

variable in lower case, awaitTermination instead of a loop.

The number of threads to use depends on several factors: the machine, the number of tasks to execute, the "size" of the task, etc.

Comment: How can I decide the waiting time. 60 seconds may bot be enough to make sure all child threads are done before i end the main thread ? That's why I used empty loop, I can not decide the time? am I right ?

Comment: Does this means no need to write create new thread statements? and also no need to start it explicitly in the constructor?

Comment: For the waiting time, it is up to you. The time should represent the time where you can say "at this time, if it's not finished, it means that there is something wrong...". It could be as well 100ms as 1 day... You do not need to create thread and to start it, the executor is designed to do that and to do it in an efficient way.

Comment: `executor.awaitTermination` returns a `boolean` telling you whether all threads were terminated. You can loop on that.

Comment: Except if you want to do something special in the loop, there is no point to make a loop. Making an infinite loop is always a bad things, mostly when a timeout mechanism is available. But you are right, I should have checked the return of `awaitTermination` and throw an error if return false.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing thread-unsafe about your first loop, if that's your concern. My only concern is what you use that `Counter` variable for: you know that you can't rely on it's value inside your `MyRunnable`s, right?

Comment: I didn't use counter inside myrunnable. I was sending it as counter for the thread creation but I find this counter does not represent the number of thread as I have a fixed pool. My constructor is: `MyRunnable (String xname)  {this.name=xname;}`. There is nothing that tells my thread to start ?? Not sure.